Add GA4 Events for Tizen and Web OS TV
I'm trying to add GA4 custom events to my project. I need to get these events to be fired from Tizen and Web OS TV
As per my understanding, I have implemented the following steps:

I have added below-mentioned script into the head tag:
<script>      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}      gtag('js', new Date());      gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', { 'debug_mode': true });      </script> 


I have added the tag to particular files:
 
if (window.gtag) {
      window.gtag('event', 'app_launch', {
        'event_category': 'App',
        'event_label': 'App Launch',
        'value': 'App Launch'
      });
    } else {
      console.error('GA4 is not initialized.');
    }



Still, events are not getting fired from Tizen and Web OS TV.
Can anyone suggest me what am I missing here or any other approach to execute the same.
